# RMSE for Multidimensional Data

Tags: python, machine-learning, multidimensional-array

For data that are one-dimensional or consist of a single column, calculating the error (**RMSE**) is simple. We can use python library, for instance

```
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error
RMSE = mean_squared_error(y_actual, y_predicted, squared=TRUE)
```

Models can have multiple output columns 2, 10 or even 100..

How to calculate **RMSE** if the data has few columns?

For example:

```
y_act = np.array([1.022,0.94,1.278,2.096,1.404,
2.035,1.622,2.348,1.909,1.678, 
1.638,1.742,2.279,1.878,2.045] ) 
y_actual = y_act.reshape((5,3))
```

```
y_pred = np.array([1.021,0.84,1.111,2.091,1.314,
2.131,1.622,2.348,1.888,1.178, 
1.238,1.632,2.119,1.677,2.145] )
y_predicted = y_pred.reshape((5,3))
```

**RMSE(y_actual - y_predicted)**?

How the formula of the error changes?

Answer (score 0):

The formula remains the same. How you use it will depend on your use case.

[image]

In your case you have 5 samples with 3 outputs(columns). Probably you ran some model on 3 different algorithms and got these results from them.

The difference from the 1D version is how you want to treat each output. You could do three things with it. In 1D version, you have just one value, here you have 3.

1. **Leave it as it is:** In this case you have an MSE value each for all 3 outputs.
2. **Uniformly Average Them:** Take the average of three MSE value you get to get one MSE value.
3. **Weighted Average:** You can do a weighted average of the three MSE values.

These functionalities are available in the sklearn under the 'multi-output' parameter.

Here are examples to help you with manual computation v/s package computation

[image]

Comment: Please do **not** post images of code; copy & paste the code here as *text*, so that it can be actually reproduced and used by the OP. Also, please do not include pleads for accepting the answer in the answer (removed).

Comment: I am running one model and I am getting ten outputs. This is multivariate example. I just formulated question simpler. I can not leave It as It is.

Comment: @desertnaut will take care of the same.

Comment: @Green - In a multivariate example, if you can't leave them as it is, then you have to come with a way to get 1 resultant value from the multiple output values. You could use the uniform-average or the weighted-average method as I highlighted above in that case.